# Linear regression - filtering of unnecessary alerts

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I use linear regression to create shorts or longs that are as accurate as possible. Unfortunately, I can't filter out unnecessary intermediate signals. Unnecessary alerts are present, especially with longer trends. Is there a way to improve my script to filter out these alerts. I've also tried countless indicators like RSI, and others. The problem here is that the indicator signals in one section unfortunately do not match in the other. Therefore, a solution with direct filtering on the candles would be the better solution for me. Thank you for an interesting idea.

Here my code:

```
// Linear regression Candels

signal_length_o = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing", minval = 1, maxval = 200, defval = 7, group="Humble LinReg Candles")
sma_signal_o = input.bool(title="Simple MA (Signal Line)", defval=true, group="Humble LinReg Candles")

lin_reg = input.bool(title="Lin Reg", defval=true, group="Humble LinReg Candles")
linreg_length = input.int(title="Linear Regression Length", minval = 1, maxval = 200, defval = 5, group="Humble LinReg Candles")

bopen = lin_reg ? ta.linreg(open, linreg_length, 0) : open
bhigh = lin_reg ? ta.linreg(high, linreg_length, 0) : high
blow = lin_reg ? ta.linreg(low, linreg_length, 0) : low
bclose = lin_reg ? ta.linreg(close, linreg_length, 0) : close

r = bopen < bclose

signal_o = sma_signal_o ? ta.sma(bclose, signal_length_o) : ta.ema(bclose, signal_length_o)

plotcandle(r ? bopen : na, r ? bhigh : na, r ? blow: na, r ? bclose : na, title="LinReg Candles", color=color.green, wickcolor=color.green, bordercolor=color.green, editable= true)
plotcandle(r ? na : bopen, r ? na : bhigh, r ? na : blow, r ? na : bclose, title="LinReg Candles", color=color.red, wickcolor=color.red, bordercolor=color.red, editable= true)

plot(signal_o, color=color.white)


plotchar(

     signal_o[3] > signal_o[2] and           // 3. Kerze > 2. Kerze
     signal_o[2] > signal_o[1] and           // 2. Kerze > 1. Kerze
     signal_o[1] >= signal_o[0] and          // 1. Signal >= Signal
     bopen < signal_o and                    // Open < Signal
     bopen[1] > bclose[1] and                // Kerze rot[1]
     bopen[0] < bclose[0] and                // Kerze grün[0]
       
     not ta.cross(open[1], signal_o) and  
     not ta.cross(low[1], signal_o) and 
     not ta.cross(open, signal_o) and 
     not ta.cross(low, signal_o)     
    
     , "Buy", "O", location.bottom, color.lime, size = size.tiny)

plotchar(

     signal_o[3] < signal_o[2] and           // 3. Kerze < 2. Kerze 
     signal_o[2] < signal_o[1] and           // 2. Kerze < 1. Kerze 
     signal_o[1] <= signal_o[0] and          // 1. Signal <= Signal 
     bopen > signal_o and                    // Open > Signal 
     bopen[1] < bclose[1] and                // Kerze grün[1] 
     bopen[0] > bclose[0] and                // Kerze rot[0]

     not ta.cross(close[1], signal_o) and
     not ta.cross(high[1], signal_o) and
     not ta.cross(open, signal_o) and
     not ta.cross(high, signal_o)
     
     , "Sell", "O", location.top, color.red,  size = size.tiny)
```

[image: See Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You should try with greater value like this one (100):

[image]

This will give you less entry points.